# How to create a 2 column design where when the first column is full, it will automatically display on the second column?

Tags: html, css

How to create a 2 column design? When the data display is full on the first column, it will automatically display on the second column?

the restriction is I cannot set a limit for the data since they are dynamic, means sometimes got 20 posts of data, but sometimes only got 2 posts. All the data have to be evenly split into 2 columns, vertically, as you can see, like the red counter text on the images attached below.

Thanks

http://img580.imageshack.us/img580/5595/readmoreq.jpg

Comment: do it on the server side (e.g. |ul with odd|ul with even|)

Answer (score 1):

Two options - use them depending on your user's browser support.

**Floats**: Float the list items while giving them half the width of the parent `ol`. The code will look something like:

```
ol {
    width: 400px;
}

ol li {
    width: 190px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: left;
}
```

**Columns**: Use the new CSS3 columns property to get the columns. Remember that only Webkit, Mozilla and Opera browsers supports this; IE as of 9 beta does not have this yet. The code will look something like:

```
ol {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
}
```

Note that the two does not produce the exact same results. You may also want to consider using a script such as [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) to detect support for CSS3 columns before using it and supplying a fallback for older browsers that do not.

See a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/sVEE5/

Answer (score 1):

Corrected according to @Yi Jiang's suggestions. Old version below

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        ul { width: 100px; float: left; border: 1px solid red; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
        var firstCol = $('#first'), 
            secondCol = $('#second');

        while(firstCol.height() < secondCol.height()){
            firstCol.append(secondCol.children().first());
        }
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="first">
        <li>Content 1</li>
        <li>Content 2</li>
        <li>Content 3</li>
        <li>Content 4</li>
        <li>Content 5</li>
        <li>Content 6</li>
        <li>Content 7</li>
        <li>Content 8</li>
        <li>Content 9</li></ul>
    <ul id="second"></ul>   
</body></html>
```

If you fill col1 and then move elements to col2. With an odd amount of elements this makes col2 taller, which is why I do it backwards

---

#### Original answer

this should be compatible even with old browsers

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    #col1, #col2 { border: 1px solid red; float:left; }
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
    var c1 = $('#col1')[0];
    var c2 = $('#col2')[0];
    while (c1.clientHeight < c2.clientHeight) {
        var elm = $('#col2 *:last')[0];
        c1.innerHTML = elm.outerHTML + c1.innerHTML;
        elm.outerHTML='';
    }
} );
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="col1">
</div>
<div id="col2">
    <div>content01</div>
    <div>content02</div>
    <div>content03</div>
    <div>content04</div>
    <div>content05</div>
    <div>content06</div>
    <div>content07</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check your code again - it's running in a infinite loop: http://jsfiddle.net/vrtam/. Also, why are you using that method of moving the elements around, instead of jQuery's own manipulation methods?

Comment: there's no infinite loop :S .. and that method is because i don't know much about jQuery

Comment: @y34h What browser are you using? `outerHTML` doesn't work in Firefox (which is why that code will go into a infinite loop, since all that's getting appended is `undefined`). See: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html

Comment: @y34h Look at the compatibility chart - Webkit and Trident both support this, but Mozilla doesn't. Also, have you looked at the code I fixed up for you there?

Comment: yes, i saw it, thx. just two things: in your version the 2nd col goes from 19 to 10; and if you put 21 elements col2 is taller ^^